# Showing diffrent data from API on different Tab Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I have 3 tab `fragments` in Activity with `viewpager` , each fragment showing different list of data from the **different** **API** **call**. 
Each fragment has different API call with progress dialog.
Now whenever i open Activity  its calling first and second's fragment's `onViewCreated` . How to prevent this ?

I also tried with  `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);` . but minimum and default is **1** .

Also found some stack answers that indicates about **Viewpager** **OnPageChangeListner**  and **setUserVisibleHint** but dont get it!  I stuck at this point . How to prevent this ?  Explain!

Comment: put your service call inside setUserVisibleHint()

Comment: check the fragment is visible or not. And call your API, if fragment is visible to user.

Answer (score 0):

**I got better answer :** `onResumeFragment()` and `onPauseFragment()`

https://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/11/02/viewpager-with-detailed-fragment-lifecycle-onresumefragment-including-source-code/